# Restart the function when the older thread dies

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, python-multithreading, algorithmic-trading

I am working on some project where I have dependency from websocket data.
And sometimes the sessions gets expired from the other side of the API.
This is how how my thread is declared.

```
streaming_thread = threading.Thread(target=stream_live_load)
streaming_thread.start()
```

I just want to know how can I use the thread ID/Number to restart when the thread dies and restart the above again on loop until I kill it specifically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to kill a Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread)

Comment: Threads have a `is_alive()` method you can used to determine if they are still running, so you could periodically check its status using that.

Comment: Why is the thread dying? If you can restart the websocket within the thread (handle the exception perhaps) then you will not need to restart the thread. Otherwise , you should look into thread pools. Python does not allow you to restart an exited thread, explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Once a thread exits in Python you can not restart it. You will have to write code to check the status of the running thread and if it exits then re-initialize a new Thread object explicitly then, start the new instance.

You can, of course, write a container object to encapsulate this behavior.

```
    import threading
    from time import sleep

    def thread_worker(arg1, arg2, arg3):
        print("run({0},{1},{2})".format(arg1,arg2,arg3))
        sleep(5)
    
    while True:
        print("Restarting thread")
        th = threading.Thread( target = thread_worker, args = (2,3,4) )
        th.start()

        while th.is_alive():
            sleep(1)
```